# How to uninstall a font

Tags: fonts, autoinst

I wanted to install a font, after searching many post and many attempts, I found that using `autoinst` is the effective way for me. However, when I used it for the first time, I didn't know how to install the bold, italics and underlining version of the font. I only installed the regular version of the font, because I only put one path after `autoinst`. After that I discover the correct way but this incorrectly installed font is left in the system. How to uninstall that?

I am using TexLive 2020 and Windows 10.